# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = wallamotop and table

Tags: php, laravel, docker, aws, docker-compose

Quiero desplegar una aplicación laravel en AWS usando docker, levanto los 3 contenedores con: docker-compose up -d
y los contenedores "mariadb" y "phpmyadmin" se levantan correctamente pero el contenedor de "myapp" se cierra. En el docker-compose.yml en el contenedor "myapp" tengo una seccion "command" donde quiero ejecutar los comandos:
"php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed"
Este error ocurre si en mi docker-compose.yml tengo puesta la sección "command" si la elimino, se me levantan los 3 contenedores y no se cierra ninguno.
Al hacer docker-compose logs -f veo que me sale este error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = wallamotop and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Este error me aparece unas veces si y unas veces no.
Si salgo de los logs y vuelvo a ejecutar "docker-compose up -d" el contenedor de "myapp" vuelve a cerrarse y en los logs aparece el mismo error, pero realiza los comandos:
"php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed"

Me gustaría solucionar el error de la conexión rechazada de la base de datos, y ser capaz de poder ejecutar los comandos "php artisan migrate php artisan db:seed" para migrar las tablas a la base de datos. Ayuda por favor.

Adjunto algunas imágenes, explicando con mas detalle
[myapp se cierra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NryY7.jpg)
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aJvb.jpg)
[salgo de los logs y vuelvo hacer docker-compose up -d, sigue el error pero ejecuta los comandos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8GNq.jpg)
[Elimino la seccion command y no se cierra myapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SLrN.jpg)
[Vuelvo añadir la seccion command, no me da error de conexión rechazada, ejecuta los comandos pero se me cierra myapp, esto ocurre muy pocas veces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgDcj.jpg)
[mi archivo config/database.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UitTz.jpg)

Mi .env es:

```
`APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sKPVZblHmpBF0G5Jgax5aucPYYfm+GPPGZn6DgePymw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://proyecto.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
.....`
```

Mi docker-compose.yml es:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_myapp
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=wallamotop 

  myapp:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

    command: sh -c "php artisan config:clear &&  php artisan migrate && php artisan db:seed"

#    command: bash -c "php artisan migrate && php artisan db:seed"


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mariadb:db
    ports:
      - '8080:80' 
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Hola. *`Connection refused `* hace pensar que las credenciales que intentas usar para conectar a la base de datos no son correctas. ¿Has verificado eso?

Comment: Por *credenciales* me refiero no sólo a nombre de usuario y contraseña, sino también al host, al puerto, al nombre de la bd. Verifica que todo es correcto en ese sentido.

Comment: si, se que el error tiene que estar por donde comenta, pero me aseguré de que las credenciales sean correctas, y juraría que así lo es

Comment: Prueba a escribir esto en consola: `php artisan db `